# UITouch, Drag and Drop not working at all

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitouch

I have a UIView and on the top of him I've got UIButton, UITableView and UINavigationBar. what I want to do is, when you click on the UIButton and drag it, all the view will move to the left side only, until the screen ends. I mean that you can drag the view to the left and when you stop touching, the view will stop where your finger stopped touching the screen.

I can't do it, he shows me only the "Touches Began 1" and thats it. what seems to be my problem here?

Thanks alot everyone!

```
float oldX, oldY;
BOOL dragging;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog("Touches Began 1");
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(btnOpen.frame, touchLocation))
    {
        NSLog("Touches Began 2");
        dragging = YES;
        oldX = touchLocation.x;
        oldY = touchLocation.y;
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (dragging)
    {
        NSLog("Dragging!");
        CGRect frame = mainView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = mainView.frame.origin.x + touchLocation.x - oldX;
        frame.origin.y =  mainView.frame.origin.y + touchLocation.y - oldY;
        mainView.frame = frame;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog("Touches Ended!");
    dragging = NO;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [btnOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btnOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(touchesMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [btnOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(touchesEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog("Touches Began 1");
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    //UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(btnOpen.frame, touchLocation))
    {
        NSLog("Touches Began 2");
        //dragging = YES;
        oldX = touchLocation.x;
        oldY = touchLocation.y;
    }
}
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   // UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(btnOpen.frame, touchLocation))
    {
        NSLog("Dragging!");
        CGRect frame = mainView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = mainView.frame.origin.x + touchLocation.x - oldX;
        frame.origin.y =  mainView.frame.origin.y + touchLocation.y - oldY;
        mainView.frame = frame;
    }
}
}
```

Try like this i think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the coordinates of the touch in relation to the frame of main view

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

And then you ask if the location of the `touchLocation` is within the frame of the buttons frame

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(btnOpen.frame, touchLocation))
```

In another words. You are checking if the touch was within the bounds of the button but you check by the coordinates of the touch made on the main view instead of the button.

So this is what you should do:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:btnOpen];
```